# sp_BlitzFirst fails when outputting values to tables

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzfirst

I have had an agent job running `sp_AskBrent` for some time, running with the following parameters:

```
EXEC sp_AskBrent @Expertmode=1
,@OutputDatabaseName = 'DBName'
, @OutputSchemaName = 'dbo'
, @OutputTableName = 'AskBrentResults'
,@seconds = 30
, @OutputTableNameFileStats='AskBrentResultsFileStats'
,@OutputTableNamePerfmonStats='AskBrentResultsPerfmonStats'
, @OutputTableNameWaitStats='AskBrentResultsWaitStats'
```

Today I wanted to update to the new renamed procedure `sp_BlitzFirst`. After creating the new procedure, I changed the code in the agent job to run `sp_BlitzFirst` instead, with the same parameters.

Everything seems to go OK until it is time to output values to the tables, then there seem to be some kind of conversion error.

The whole history output is as follows:

> Setting up configuration variables [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Now starting diagnostic analysis [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Capturing first pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Beginning investigatory queries [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Finished running investigatory queries [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Waiting to match @Seconds parameter [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Capturing second pass of wait stats, perfmon counters, file stats [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Analyzing changes between first and second passes of DMVs [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Analysis finished, outputting results [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. [SQLSTATE 22007] (Error 241).  The step failed.

Anyone have any suggestions to what might cause this? Have the output tables changed somehow since the procedure was called `sp_Askbrent`? The version of `sp_Askbrent` was reported this way: sp_AskBrent (TM) v20 as of Jan  1 2016 12:00AM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we renamed it sp_BlitzFirst and went open source, we made several breaking changes, one of which was changing the history table's DATETIME field to be DATETIMEOFFSET instead:

https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/288

I would use a new history table name, and then it'll get automatically created with the right datatype.